# How to add state tracking AWS iOS?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I am having trouble using this code from AWS documentation to check the user state. No matter where I place it prints nothing. I also have properly set up my project with the AWS iOS SDK. I have placed in the `AppDelegate` and in different view controller's `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` however it still prints nothing.

```
AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in
            switch (userState) {
            case .guest:
                print("user is in guest mode.")
            case .signedOut:
                print("user signed out")
            case .signedIn:
                print("user is signed in.")
            case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
                print("need to login again.")
            case .signedOutFederatedTokensInvalid:
                print("user logged in via federation, but currently needs new tokens")
            default:
                print("unsupported")
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you initializing SDK (i.e.`AWSMobileClient.default().initialize`) and changing authentication state though? nothing will happen if you don't

Comment: @KirilS I am fairly new to swift and the AWS documentation. Could you show me the proper way to implement this?

Comment: AWS github repo has some basic examples. Here's the minimal one that shows initialization: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/59d905a66179f955deedc4473519689ba56fe2dd/AWSAuthSDK/AWSAuthSDKTestApp/ViewController.swift